# Steam support for Rift without re-downloading?

Tags: steam, rift

I downloaded Rift for my PC a few months ago. But seeing that it has been released on Steam now, I want to play it with Steam Support.

Can I do this without having to re-download the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steam-enabled games can only be played by downloading them through Steam; you can't have them downloaded from another location. Unfortunately you have to re-download it because Steam is using its own files for games.

Answer (score 3):

Let Steam download 1-2% of the game, then close Steam. Now browse to the **SteamApps\downloading** folder under Steam's install location, and  place your existing Rift files inside the **gameid** folder (*39120*).  Open Steam and it should start performing a check of the files' integrity, with chances being that only the game executable and steamapi.dll would need a refresh.

Comment: Don't know about this cause the Rift client downloads the data files, NOT steam.

Comment: So couldn't you put your rift client and files in the appropriate SteamApps folder, and let steam just download what it needs to run the client, which will download what it needs to play the game?

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work at all.  Steam didn't automatically check the cache integrity and manually doing it finished in seconds without changing anything.  I tried to recreate the directory structure for the fully installed game (as opposed to the downloading structure) and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

What kinds of Steam support are you looking for? If you want to avoid the re-download (required since the files are different) you can make it a non-Steam game shortcut and launch with Steam to have the Shift-Tab menu and all manner of features — just not the integrated kind. If you want those features then you will indeed have to re-download it.